# Спам Nouveau при установке Arch linux

Tags: linux, grub, archlinux, uefi

При установке Arch linux, хоть а UEFI хоть без, выходит куча ошибок
А конкретно,
nouveau SCHED_ERROR

вот скрин происхрдящего [image: Скрин происходящего]

Comment: на машине есть карточка nvidia?

Comment: Есть, но я уже установил, саму систему, добавив nouveay.modeset=0, но тут такая же проблема при загрузке системы

Comment: возможно, карточка не совместима, или она не включилась